# AVA tests called within a function working on mac, but not on linux

Tags: ava

I have some AVA tests that I am trying to run multiple times, but on different mocks. For example, I want to run the same 5 tests, but ensure that these tests work for variously structured data. I've devised a way to import mocks into the test file and compare them to how they should parse out which looks similar to the following:

```js
import test from 'ava';
import * as fs from 'fs';

let mockSampleEmail;
let mockDecomposedEmail;

function readJsonFile(fname) {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(fname).toString());
}

fs.readdir('pre', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.match(/\.json$/)) {
      return null;
    }
    mockSampleEmail     = readJsonFile("pre/" + file);
    mockDecomposedEmail = readJsonFile("post/" + file);
    runEmailDecomposerTests(mockSampleEmail, mockDecomposedEmail, mockRiskyUpdates, file);
  })
})
```

The runEmailDecomposerTests function looks like this:

```js
const runEmailDecomposerTests = (mockSampleEmail, mockDecomposedEmail, mockRiskyUpdates, fname) => {
  test(`(${fname})  Converts the email message received from the websocket into a simple email object`, t => {
    //Assertions here
  })
}
```

My Directory structure looks like this:

```
test/
--emails/
----emailDecomposer.spec.js
----pre/
------sampleEmail.json
----post/
------sampleEmail.json
```

This all works locally on my mac, but when I push it up to our jenkins server to test for continuous integration, it fails with the error:

```
 ✖ No tests found in test/emails/emailDecomposer.spec.js
```

Even though I can confirm that the runEmailDecomposerTests function is definitely being called. The confusing part is that it passes locally on my mac. The jenkins server is a Linux vm so that's why I'm leaning towards a mac/linux issue, but I can't be sure. Even further, about one in 5 times it passes on our CI server, so maybe its a race condition of some kind?

Comment: I've tested it on a linux VM that isn't jenkins and there is a similar issue. So its definitely linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AVA docs:

> **You must define all tests synchronously.** They can't be defined inside `setTimeout`, `setImmediate`, etc.

`fs.readdir` is async, so I'm surprised it actually works on macOS, but as you've experienced, it leads to race issues. I would suggest either switching to `fs.readdirSync` or doing the async operation in a [`test.before()`](https://github.com/avajs/ava#before--after-hooks) hook and then take advantage of `t.context`.

Comment: You're a god. Thank you!